# Motivation behind the definition of paracompact.

Tags: general-topology, intuition, motivation, paracompactness

I am self-studying topology.I encountered the definition of a paracompact space.A collection $\mathcal A$ of subsets of $X$ is said to be locally finite if each point in $X$ has an open neighborhood that intersects only finitely many members of the collection.Then comes the definition of paracompact space.A space $X$ is said to be paracompact if every open cover has a locally finite open refinement.I want to know what is the motivation behind such a weird definition.I want to know what gave rise to the study of paracompactness,not historically but rather I want to get an intuition behind these things.Can someone help me?

Comment: Paracompactness is a technical condition under which one can prove the existence of partitions of unit on manifolds. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity

Comment: In "Modern Analysis and Topology" by Norman Howes. He says that J. Dieudonne introduced paracompactness as the "natural" generalization of compactness, and as a tool for studying metrization. By the same time, Tukey studied full normallity as a generalization of normality. Then H. Stone proved this concepts to be equivalent.

Comment: I have heard it said that paracompact was felt to be the "right" intermediate between $T_4$ and metrizable.

Comment: In the def'n, shouldn't that be a locally finite $open$ refinement?